# Select the right architecture for simple java bean application

Tags: java, sql, xml, database, xslt

I need to make a simple java application, and now I am working on the architecture for this. Please, help me to build way to make my app. I only need advice on how to make this (what classes I need, what methods to include), but the code I will write myself. If it is not difficult for you, please write your opinion about the best and right way to make my app. Thanks!

### My technical task below:

Given: TEST table in any database (use in memory databases are not recommended), containing one integer column (FIELD).

You must write a console application in Java, using standard library JDK7 (preferably) or JDK8 and implements the following functionality:

1. The main application class must follow the rules of JavaBean, that is initialized through the setters. Initialization parameters - the data to connect to the database and the number N.
2. Upon launch, the application inserts a TEST N records with values ​​1..N. If the TEST table were recording, they are removed before inserting.
3. The application then requests the data from TEST.FIELD and generates the correct XML-type document

   > ```
   > <entries>
   > <Entry>
   > <Field> field to field </ field>
   > </ Entry>
   > ...
   > <Entry>
   > <Field> field to field </ field>
   > </ Entry>
   > </ entries>
   > ```

(with N nested elements ) The document is saved in the file system as "1.xml".

4. By means of XSLT, the application converts the contents of the "1.xml" to the 
   following form:

> < entries> < entry> < field>value of field 'field' < /entry> ...
>   < entry> < field>value of field 'field' < /entry>

(with N nested elements ) The new document is saved in the file system as "2.xml".

5. The application parses "2.xml" and outputs the arithmetic sum of the values ​​of all the attributes field in the console.
6. For large N (~ 1,000,000) while the application should not be more than five minutes.

Comment: You should look at [this help page about how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Have you looked for a Java tutorial?  It sounds like one might help you.

Comment: yes, i looked for a Java tutorial, but my knowlege is only make it in a one class mail, i think it is not right way and require profi advice. thanks.